# Trying to deploy a script to Heroku and I get this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a python script to Heroku, when I enter this line `git push heroku master`.

It gives me this error `ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-y_748suf` and `Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.`
what's the problem here?

requirements file:

```
APScheduler==3.6.3
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
chromedriver-binary==85.0.4183.38.0
CurrencyConverter==0.14.2
html-parser==0.2
idna==2.10
IMDbPY==6.8
lxml==4.5.1
MouseInfo==0.1.3
numpy==1.19.0
opencv-python==4.3.0.36
pandas==1.0.5
Pillow==7.2.0
ply==3.11
PyAutoGUI==0.9.50
PyDirectInput==1.0.2
PyGetWindow==0.0.8
PyJWT==1.7.1
PyMsgBox==1.0.8
pynput==1.7.1
pyperclip==1.8.0
PyRect==0.1.4
PyScreeze==0.1.26
pyTelegramBotAPI==3.7.2
pytesseract==0.3.4
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-pdf==0.37
PyTweening==1.0.3
pytz==2020.1
pywhatkit==2.4
query-string==0.0.0
request==0.0.0
requests==2.24.0
schedule==0.6.0
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
telegram==0.0.1
twilio==6.43.0
tzlocal==2.1
urllib3==1.25.9
wikipedia==1.4.0
```

I don't know why all of them are there, I just want selenium and datatime and time

Guys, I'm totally new to these deployment stuff, so please no hardcore words.

I wish anybody can help me with that, Thanks in advance

Comment: Share the content of your `requirements.txt` file

Comment: Use a [python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). Only install necessary packages. Get it to work locally. Generate a new `requirements.txt`.